# Install Ubuntu in windows 8.1 preview

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 8.1 preview PC. I am trying to install Ubuntu through USB drive. But no luck. Does anyone succeeded?

More info: My PC came with windows 8 pre-installed. In that version I was able to install Ubuntu. Now I installed Windows8.1 preview after doing that I am unable to install any version of Ubuntu. It just loads from USB and running from USB. When I select install, it just reboots and loading from USB and not installing anything.

Comment: Does it has UEFI, secure boot ON ? And WHICH version of Ubuntu you trying to install? Please [Check this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: It seems unlikely that any PC shipped with the Windows 8.1 **preview** installed by the OEM. Therefore, this is *not* the same question as [Installing on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported) (that Windows 8 sometimes requires "Secure Boot" to be enabled is fundamentally related to systems on which it's pre-installed by an OEM), though it's possible some information from there may be helpful.

Comment: I checked the referred links. But no luck. Thanks.